# Changing which object is referred to?

Tags: c#

I'm new to using c# and I want to change the writing permissions in a `TextBox` according to a condition: my code right now looks like this

```
for(int j = 0; j<ports.Count(); j++)
{
    if(ports[j] != "Not In Use")
    {
        runBootLoader(ports[j]); // is supposed to run multiple bootloaders
    }
    else
    {
        txtBoxSerial1.Enabled = false;
    }           
}
```

`txtBoxSerial1.Enabled = false;` is what i use to revoke writing rights. I have 20 different textboxes, and i want to be able to change which of them I write to, maybe by using the iteration of a for loop.

Is there anyway to use a placeholder or another method to do this?

Comment: How did you instantiate these boxes, presumably through the VS designer?

Comment: If any textbox is associated to a port (defined in the ports array) then you could recognize this association if you set the Tag property of the textboxes to the index of the relative port in the array

Comment: Do you want to a completely random textbox, or do you have some sort of pattern or order in mind?  And when do you want the writing to occur?

Comment: yes through vs designer. 
 
@LordWilmore no i want to use the txtboxserial according to the iteartion of the for loop. i have them named from 1-20

Comment: i want to do something like txtBoxSerial [ j ] = false; although that syntax is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the control by name, so basically like this:

```
string textboxName = String.Format( "textbox{0}", textBoxNumber );
Control[] textBoxes = this.Controls.Find( textboxName, true );
if (textBoxes != null && textBoxes.Length > 0)
{
    textBoxes[0].Text = "Hello";
}
```

Is that what you're after?  If it is then consider setting up a collection (e.g. array, list, etc) of the textboxes once at startup, and then just access the array after that, to save making a call to `Find()` each time.